# string stringName {get; set;} vs stringName stringName {get; set;}

Tags: c#, .net

I just started learning C# and I saw something like this:

```
public class Name
{
  string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

VS

```
public class Name
{
  FirstName FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

Can someone explain the difference between the two? When to use one vs the other?

Comment: The second one is only legal if you have a class, struct, enum, or delegate type named `FirstName`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one declares that the property is of type `string`:

```
string FirstName {get; set;}
```

The second declares that the property is of type `FirstName`:

```
FirstName FirstName {get; set;}
```

So I imagine your scenario is like this:

```
public class Name
{
    public FirstName FirstName {get;set;}
    public LastName LastName {get;set;}
}

public class FirstName 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class LastName
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

In C# there are two kinds of data types:
1. Inbuilt - they are part of the language.
2. User-defined - they are part of your code, or the code of a library you are using.

`String` (or, to use its fully qualified name: `System.String`) is part part of the language itself. Some types are part of the .NET framework and you can, for all intents and purposes, consider these the same as 1.

Other types are defined in code, or the code of third-party libraries that you use. These are considered to be user-defined types. In your case, `FirstName` will be a user-defined type (probably a `class` or a `struct`).

Comment: Can we say it has defined datatypes(FirstName)?

Comment: @kvk30 What do you mean?

Comment: A string is inbuilt datatype.net or any programming language. Any programming language can allow us to define our own datatypes, right? Similarly, In this case, he had defined his own datatype name `FirstName`. If anything is wrong, correct me.

Comment: For which one you are saying no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161076/discussion-between-kvk30-and-john).

Answer (score 1):

I give you as simple answer as can be. Here `FirstName FirstName {get; set;}`
you have

```
FirstName // type identifier
FirstName // identifier
{get; set;} // access modifier
```

Since `FirstName` in position of "type identifier" is a type. Your question boils down to, "what is difference between `string` and `FirstName`"?

Well, we all know the type called `System.String`, shortly `string`. It is provided by Microsoft. But what about `FirstName`? What is the full namespace for it? Sort of like asking difference between `string` and `int`. They both types, both derive from `object` but everything else is different.

Now, it is totally possible for a class as this

```
class FirstName
{
    FirstName FirstName {get; set;} 
}
```

In this case you have a class `FirstName` that contains property `FirstName`, which will return (if set) object of type `FirstName`, which is of same object type as defined by class `FirstName`, and which will contain a property `FirstName`, and so on.